# How to remove only intent-to-add files from index in git?

Tags: git

Is there a way to remove from an index with a single command only those files that have been added with -N flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Git doesn't keep track of which files were added with `-N` and which were simply empty.

Comment: Is this still true? After `git add -N`, I can see in `git status` that some files are `new files` and others are `modified`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is! Using only git:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A -z \
    | git restore --staged -q --pathspec-file-nul --pathspec-from-file=-
```

Files that are added without their content with `-N` show up as 'Added' (`A`) in the work tree, and that is what is listed with `--diff-filter=A`. This list is then piped into `git restore` which removes the intent-to-add.

I used `git restore` because `git reset` just resets the whole index if there are no files added with `-N` (because the pathspec is empty). You can also avoid this problem with

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A -z | xargs -r0 git reset -q --
```

which requires GNU xargs.

Comment: issue with this command is that it removes all your added files from changes to be committed also